# Fragment invisibility

Tags: android, android-fragments, visibility

I have an Activity that shows two Fragments side by side. FragmentB has to be invisible until a button is clicked in FragmentA. Is there a way to make a fragment invisible? (Both fragments are still there but there is a blank space until FragmentB becomes visible)

What do I have to do and in what file should I make changes? Can I have an example please?

The files:
MainActivity.java,   FragmentA.java , FragmentB.java, activity_main.xml, fraga.xml, fragb.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the place of fragment B with an empty FrameLayout. On button click, add the fragment B to that Framelayout (Create it)

```
public void atButtonClicked()
{
    FragmentB b = new FragmentB();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmeLayout, b);
    transaction.commit();
}
```